# Calculating the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan x}{x(\ln(x+2))^2} dx$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to prove that the integral of the following function converges:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan x}{x(\ln(x+2))^2} dx$$
it's easy to prove that for each integral starting from $1$ using Dirichlet but i didn't manage to proof for the integral starting at $0$

Can I have a hint?
Thank you

Comment: The title is a bit misleading since *calculating* an indefinite integral is usually much more difficult than proving its convergence only.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x\ln^2(x+2)}=\frac{1}{\ln^2(2)}$$ and thus it's prolongeable by continuity at $0$.

Comment: you supposed to get 0/0, what am i missing?

Comment: The very standard limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}=1.$ @MyNick

Answer (score 2):

$\int_2^{\infty} \frac 1 {x(\log\, x)^{2}}\, dx <\infty$ as seen easily buy the substitution  $y=\log\, x$. Now just use the fact that $\arctan$ is bounded. Integrability near $0$ is clear.

Comment: i dont see how it's clear, can you give anotgher hint please?

Comment: $\frac {\arctan\, x} x \to 1$ as $ x \to 0$ (by L'Hopital's Rule) so the integrand is bounded on $(0,2)$. Is this the part where you had difficulty?

Comment: didn't know that limit. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem around $x=0$ since, by Taylor expansion,
$$\frac{\tan ^{-1}(x)}{x \log ^2(x+2)}=\frac{1}{\log ^2(2)}-\frac{x}{\log ^3(2)}+O\left(x^2\right)$$

I do not finish since Kavi Rama Murthy explained what is going on for infinite values of $x$.